# Janus MCU solution for the video call

Tags: plugins, video-streaming, gstreamer, janus

I am finding the Janus MCU solution for the video call. I know Janus has supported the SFU solution for the video call and has supported the MCU solution for the audio call.
Is there anyone who can help me?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you have to create your own Janus plugin for that or use different tool.

Comment: Could you let me know how I can create my own Janus plugin for MCU?

Comment: It will be pretty complex and time consuming task... I would recommend you look to implementation of existing Janus plugins: https://github.com/meetecho/janus-gateway/tree/master/plugins